# How to boost Solr relevancy score by inverse of geodist()

Tags: solr, lucene, distance, geospatial, solr-boost

So I've implemented and successfully used Solr 4. I've got to say that Solr 4 is awesome! Anyway I successfully sorted by distance and used a geofilter to limit the results to a certain area.  What I would like to do now is boost the relevancy score by the inverse of the distance.  This page talks about it but doesn't say how to do it (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch)

I've tried the following but it gives me an error:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q={!boost b=recip(geodist(), 1, 1000, 1000)}...`

The error I get is:

`org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Expected identifier at pos 27 str='{!boost b=recip(geodist(), 1, 10 in ...`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#How_to_boost_closest_results

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You still need to specify the main part of your query after the boost function:

```
q={!boost b=recip(geodist(),1,1000,1000)}foo:bar&...
```

If you're only interested in boosting by the inverse of the distance you can use a wildcard query:

```
q={!boost b=recip(geodist(),1,1000,1000)}*&...
```

...or use the function query parser:

```
q={!func}recip(geodist(),1,1000,1000)&...
```

You also need to specify the lat/long values and spatial field to query against either as arguments of the geodist function:

```
q={!boost b=recip(geodist(50.1, -0.86, myGeoField),1,1000,1000)}foo:bar&...
```

...or factored out as query string parameters:

```
q={!boost b=recip(geodist(),1,1000,1000)}foo:bar&sfield=myGeoField&pt=50.1,-0.86
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes the part of the query I was messing up on was specifying the lat/long and the spatial field! Thanks again!

Comment: Just FYI, In solr 3.x you will need to remove spaces in between the commas for the parameters

Comment: @PsychoDad Holy moly, that is one nasty gotcha. Solved a problem for me, thanks heaps!

Comment: I have edited the answer to remove the gotcha spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that i get better results with...

```
{!boost b=recip(geodist(),1,100,10)}
```

I don't know what causes this, but I wish Solr gave a little more information on the parameters for the recip and boost.
[Current Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#How_to_boost_closest_results) is lacking.

Comment: recip() is a function ``recip(x,m,a,b)`` of the form  ``a/(m*x+b)``.  When a,b are the same value it returns a value in the range of 0 to 1.  As a,b become larger, there is less variance in the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, here is a distance boost used at my place of work.  It's different than the one on the Solr documentation site.  This boost function will treat distance equally for a number of kilomteres before the boosting begins.  This is useful in some situations, where you don't want relevancy changes for small differences in distances.

You can change the constant `25` to be any number of kilometers that you want the boost to be the same.

You can define the distance boost as such:

```
div(1.0, min(1000, max(25, geodist())))
```

[image: distance boost plot]